# Call requires API level 21 (current min is 19): android.view.View()

Tags: android, view, sdk, android-custom-view

So I want to create a library that use custom view. I want to inherit View class, but it's error because my minsdk is 19. I need my library to support sdk 19. Is there a way to solve this?

```
class Dummy() :  View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another constructor for this. The one you used is available only from the API 21.

For custom views I use it like this:

```
class Dummy @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0)
: View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
```

So 2 things here:

1. Use View constructor with 3 params. Context, attrs, defStyleAttr.
2. Use @JvmOverloads annotation and default values for parameters to support actually 3 constructors in one line.

Comment: it works, i love you. but is there a downside to use this constructor? are there unsupported feature or something else?

Comment: There is no downside. defStyleRes is just for default style to apply if defStyleAttr == 0. You probably will never need them. Even if you will need to support something like that, you can add it just to your custom view constructor and modify init-block logic.